# How do I make it so that when someone presses submit, the form clears?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, submit

I have a website that I made from HTML and CSS. In it I have a contact form. I am not using this form for real, so I do not need it to actually send me the data that is inputted, but I do need it to clear the form when someone presses submit. The code I am using is:

```
<div class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="fullName" placeholder="Your name">
                    <label for="fullName">Your name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
                    <label for="email">Your email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                </div>

                <div class="spacer10"></div>

                <div class="center-btn-wrapper">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add all things in a form tag and then use the reset() method in the script tag or in your javascript file like this:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you are using any frameworks, I think this should help just set fields to the empty string after submitting with js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form" id="myForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="fullName" placeholder="Your name">
                    <label for="fullName">Your name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
                    <label for="email">Your email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                </div>

                <div class="spacer10"></div>

                <div class="center-btn-wrapper">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="clearForm()">Send</button>
                </div>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function clearForm(){
  document.getElementById('fullName').value = '';
  document.getElementById('email').value = '';
  document.getElementById('message').value = '';
}
</script>
```